# Scaffold database at once?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a tool or means to scaffold all tables in a DB in one step?

Right now I am doing this with a series of repetitive tasks:

- Create Area: DBName
- Add Entity Framework model for DBName to Area
- For each table:

  - Add new Scaffold to generate Controllers and Views for Table

This certainly works with DB first development.  However, this is such a basic set of steps I am surprised I cannot simply generate the controllers and views from the DB('s) at once.  Is this possible?